# Retrieving Text from IP Address control in c

Tags: c, winapi, ip-address

```
    SendMessage(hIpControl, IPM_GETADDRESS, 0, (LPARAM)lpIPAddress);
    TextOut(hdc, 10, 10, (LPCWSTR)lpIPAddress , 20);
//where static LPDWORD lpIPAddress = (LPDWORD)malloc(sizeof(LPDWORD));
```

and 
hIpControl is a handle to an IP control. When I run this the Text Out just displays random chinese symbols and stuff. How can I safely retrieve the IP address and store it in a string. I need to get it in a string like: "192.168.1.4" in order for my app to work.

Comment: "Since the compiler was unable to convert the parameter, let's give it some help and stick a cast in front. [There, that shut up the compiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/23/9911891.aspx). Those compiler guys are so stupid. They can't even figure out how to convert one pointer to another. I bet they need help wiping their butts when they go to the bathroom." ([Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx))

Comment: @Adam: In case of classic windows messages you have to use casts. Those are just not type save.

Comment: @Ole: For the `WPARAM` and `LPARAM` parameters of `SendMessage` et al, yes, it's unfortunate, but for the string parameter of `TextOut`?  "Please give me a null-terminated wide string" should not be responded to with "Ok, here's a 32-bit integer, but I promise it's really a null-terminated wide string, mkay?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IPM_GETADDRESS` returns the address as a `DWORD`, not as a string.

```
DWORD dwAddr;
int iCount = (int)SendMessage(hwndCtl, IPM_GETADDRESS, 0, (LPARAM)&dwAddr);
wchar_t wchAddr[20];
StringCchPrintf(wchAddr, _countof(wchAddr), L"%ld.%ld.%ld.%ld",
    FIRST_IPADDRESS(dwAddr),
    SECOND_IPADDRESS(dwAddr),
    THIRD_IPADDRESS(dwAddr),
    FOURTH_IPADDRESS(dwAddr));
```

Note that it's possible for the user to enter fewer than all four quads (`iCount` in the above example contains the number of quads returned) so you would need to account for this in real life.

Answer (score 3):

This would give you all 4 fields into string.

```
DWORD lpIPAddress;

LRESULT SM = SendMessage(hWndIPAddress, IPM_GETADDRESS, 0, (LPARAM)(LPDWORD)&lpIPAddress);

BYTE IPPart1 = FIRST_IPADDRESS((LPARAM)lpIPAddress);
BYTE IPPart2 = SECOND_IPADDRESS((LPARAM)lpIPAddress);
BYTE IPPart3 = THIRD_IPADDRESS((LPARAM)lpIPAddress);
BYTE IPPart4 = FOURTH_IPADDRESS((LPARAM)lpIPAddress);


AnsiString ip = AnsiString(IPPart1) + AnsiString(".") +
                AnsiString(IPPart2) + AnsiString(".") +
                AnsiString(IPPart3) + AnsiString(".") +
                AnsiString(IPPart4);

ShowMessage("IP Address " + ip);
```

Reference : http://www.functionx.com/cppbuilder/controls/ipaddress.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
DWORD IPAddress;
SendMessage(hIpControl, IPM_GETADDRESS, 0, (LPARAM)&IPAddress);
WCHAR Buff[500];
sprintf(Buff, "%d.%d.%d.%d", (int)FIRST_IPADDRESS(IPAddress), (int)SECOND_IPADDRESS(IPAddress), (int)THIRD_IPADDRESS(IPAddress), (int)FOURTH_IPADDRESS(IPAddress));
TextOut(hdc, 10, 10, Buff , 20);
```

Or maybe you have to change the oder of FIRST to FOURTH - dont know exactly :-)
see here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here a Simple Function that should work Fine (as it did for me) :

```
void getIpAddress(HWND hDlg)
{
    int len = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_IPADDRESS_INPUT));
    if (len > 0)
    {
        char *buffer;
        buffer = (char*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, len + 1);
        GetDlgItemTextA(hDlg, IDC_IPADDRESS_INPUT, buffer, len + 1);
        MessageBoxA(0, buffer, "Ip Address", MB_OK);
    }
    else
    {
        // Error handling here
    }
}
```